# document.queryCommandValue returns (empty string) in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, contenteditable

I want to read if a certain text in a contenteditable element is bold or not. In Chrome `document.queryCommandValue("bold")` returns `"true"/"false"` as a string, IE returns a `true/false` as a boolean, but Firefox returns `(empty string)` in the developer console.

I made a fiddle as an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/nTQd2/

If you write som text in the div, mark it and then hit "Bold" the span should show `"true"/"false"` or `true/false`. I don't really care if its as a string or a boolean as I can convert it later.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For bold, italic and similar, use [`document.queryCommandState()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Use `document.queryCommandValue()` for non-Boolean commands.

http://jsfiddle.net/nTQd2/1/

Answer (score 1):

That's simple.

```
Document.queryCommandValue()
```

returns a string. Instead of that use this.

```
Document.queryCommandState('Bold')
```

This will return a boolean value as true/false.

Example:

```
function isSelectedTextBold()
{
    var isBold = document.queryCommandState("Bold");
    return isBold;
}
```

I am also specifying function calls for other formatting options.

1. Italic -> document.queryCommandState("Italic");
2. Underline -> document.queryCommandState("Underline");
3. Left Justify -> document.queryCommandState("justifyLeft");
4. Center Justify -> document.queryCommandState("justifyCenter");
5. Right Justify -> document.queryCommandState("justifyRight");

I hope this helps. :)