# How to make execCommand work on IE and firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox, rich-text-editor

I'm working on creating a rich text editor using contenteditable div.The code works fine in chrome,but it doesn't seem to work in IE and Firefox.Only formatting works in IE and Firefox but the highlighting functionality doesn't work.
Below is code link 
https://jsbin.com/vunenociwu

```
<div class='rte'>
<div class='rtecontrol'>
    <img class="hi" onclick="document.execCommand('bold',false,null);hmm();" src='http://jeevan.tx0.org/rteditor/icons/text_bold.png' unselectable="on" >
    <img class="hi" onclick="document.execCommand('italic',false,null);hmm();" src='http://jeevan.tx0.org/rteditor/icons/text_italic.png'>
    <img class="hi" onclick ="document.execCommand('underline',false,null);hmm();" src='http://jeevan.tx0.org/rteditor/icons/text_underline.png'>
</div>
<div class='rtearea'  contenteditable='true'>
    Hello world;
</div>
```

```
    var imageTags = document.getElementsByClassName("hi");

    setInterval(function () {
    var isBold = document.queryCommandValue("Bold");
    var isItalic = document.queryCommandValue("Italic");
    var isUnderlined = document.queryCommandValue("Underline");
    if (isBold === 'true') {
        imageTags[0].style.opacity = 1;
    } else {
        imageTags[0].style.opacity = 0.5;
    }

    if (isItalic === 'true') {
        imageTags[1].style.opacity = 1;
    } else {
        imageTags[1].style.opacity = 0.5;
    }
    if (isUnderlined === 'true') {
        imageTags[2].style.opacity = 1;
    } else {
        imageTags[2].style.opacity = 0.5;
    }
}, 100)'
```

Comment: For bold, italic and similar, Use `queryCommandState` instead `queryCommandValue` 
[refer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20946860/5561276).  [Edited Code](https://jsbin.com/valopiveji/edit?js,output)

Comment: thanks for the help :) It works !